# Python: combining dictionary values

Tags: python

I'm building a test program to generate random passwords with the purpose of learning python, I'm actually using this code to list possible dictionaries to be used:

```
def symbol_switcher(arg):
    switcher = {
        1: DICTIONARY_LETTERS_UPPER,
        2: DICTIONARY_LETTERS_LOWER,
        3: DICTIONARY_NUMBERS_DEC,
        4: DICTIONARY_SYMBOLS
    }
    return switcher.get(arg)
```

I ask via command line, what dictionary the user wants to use, so any combination can work. In the switcher above values are 1~4 however I need to build it so that values are 1,2,4,8 accepting any value in range 1~15 where for example 11 (i,2,8) means the first, second and fourth dictionaries.

How can I assign to my `dictionary_touse` variable the result of the user selection without having to do multiple `if` and without evaluating the value against possible cominations?

In short is something like possible in python?

```
#assign the resulting join of switcher elements
dictionary_touse = symbol_switcher(11)
```

**edit**:

I actually use this method, it might be wrong and it is not what I intended, I have no problems in rewriting the dictionary if this helps:

[image]

the issue with this method is that Im getting this error:

`TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

**edit**: apparently notepad++ likes to add arbitrari TAB instead of spaces, this makes python angry, I showed the symbols and replaced all TABs occurrences with four spaces for indentation.

Comment: why does 11 correspond to first (1), second (2) and forth (8)? Because 1+2+8 = 11?

Comment: So how should the function return multiple dicts? Should it wrap them in a list like `[DICTIONARY_LETTERS_UPPER, DICTIONARY_LETTERS_LOWER, DICTIONARY_SYMBOLS]`?

Comment: It'd be easier if you refactored your dictionary to use 0-3 instead of 1-4, then you could use bit fiddling more easily.

Comment: @guidot the all capital are string constants, not dictionaries

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yes it is a convention to enumerate and combine multiple values, imagine having a DB instead of storing 4 fields true/false you can have it managed with a single field, imagine if you have multiple flags that can be true/false. This system helps in saving space on a DB and allow you to combine flags in any possible combination, you just have to double the value every next value.

Comment: Please describe how the combined dictionaries, comprised of whatever kind of values are in `DICTIONARY_LETTERS_UPPER`, `DICTIONARY_LETTERS_LOWER`, `DICTIONARY_NUMBERS_DEC`, and `DICTIONARY_SYMBOLS`, etc, are to be returned. This is crucial information you've left out of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
def symbol_switcher(arg):
    switcher = {
        1: DICTIONARY_LETTERS_UPPER,
        2: DICTIONARY_LETTERS_LOWER,
        3: DICTIONARY_NUMBERS_DEC,
        4: DICTIONARY_SYMBOLS
    }
    return [switcher.get(key) for key in switcher if key & arg]
```

Comment: Bit operations with 1, 2, 3 and 4? That doesn't look like it'll work as intended.

Comment: Would it look more like working if the keys would be 0x1, 0x2, 0b11, 0b100?

Comment: No, that would look like you're trying to deliberately confuse people who read your code. Why would you mix hex and binary numbers like that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem, I think you can do:

```
def symbol_switcher(arg):
    switcher = {
        1: DICTIONARY_LETTERS_UPPER,
        2: DICTIONARY_LETTERS_LOWER,
        3: DICTIONARY_NUMBERS_DEC,
        4: DICTIONARY_SYMBOLS
    }
    # return the power p + 1 corresponding to the power decomposition of 2 of arg
    # p+1 is related to the numbers in switcher
    list_ind = [p+1 for p,v in enumerate(bin(arg)[:1:-1]) if int(v)]
    # get a list of dictionnary define in switcher linked to element of list_ind
    list_dict = [switcher.get(i) for i in list_ind]
    # Create a concatenate dictionnary with all items of all dictionary selected.
    return {k: v for d in list_dict for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would code it like this, combining the example bit mask with (here: constants instead of variables) and joining it using string join operation, giving a string result:

```
def symbol_switcher(control):
    return "".join([s for i, s in zip((1, 2, 4, 8), 
                                      ("ABC", "abc", "123", "+-:.")) 
                    if i & control])
```